# How to Draw info window on google map (web) using table row onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map on my end a plain map of my city something like this

```
function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.1, 2.2);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

}

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

then I have a table that data comes from my database

```
<table>
  <tr class="row">
     <td>1.8</td>
     <td>1.2</td>
     <td>this is sample description 1</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr class="row">
     <td>2.1</td>
     <td>1.3</td>
     <td>this is sample description 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
     <td>1.2</td>
     <td>Longitude</td>
     <td>this is sample description 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then I have a ready function that will get the data of row

```
   $(function() {
    $(".row_data").click(function(){  
            var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
            }).get();
            tableData // this is the row data       
    });
```

what I need to do is open infowindow base on the data I got from clicking one of my rows.

I have search on this but most of the available ways is 
- the infowindow is preloaded

could anyone help me with my approach I try to use on how to add listener like this

```
 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content:  window_detail
                            });
                         infowindow.open(map);
```

but it doesn't seem right and its not working.

Could you help me, and Im new to this so please spare me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple, you would add an infoWindow in the `$(".row_data").click` method to add it when needed.

Something along these lines (not tested, just for general idea)

Javascript:

```
$(".row_data").click(function(){  
  //get your table data as an object
  // Now make sure that if an infoWindow exists you close it 
  if (infoWindow !== null) {
        infoWindow.close();
        infoWindow = null;
  }
  // Now add a new infoWindow based on your data
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Some content here',
    position: new google.maps.latLng(/* put in data here from table */)
  });
  //now open the infowindow in particular map
  infoWindow.open(someMap);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

drag out the content of the the clicked row using `eq()` and assign the values to the already created infowindow :

in a `typical initialize()` :

```
..
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
..
```

assign a click event to each of the rows in the table :

```
$("#table tr").on('click', function() {
   var lat = parseFloat($(this).find('td').eq(0).text());
   var lng = parseFloat($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
   var content = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html(); 
   var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
   infoWindow.setPosition(latLng);
   infoWindow.setContent(content);
   infoWindow.open(map);
});
```

working fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mhS9u/**